# loop over name attribute that has an array

Tags: jquery, loops

i have a form which contains multiple input text box that will take emails.

```
<li style="text-decoration: none" id="email1"><input type="text" name="email[]" /></li>
<li style="text-decoration: none" id="email2"><input type="text" name="email[]" /></li>
```

There will also be option to add more input fields.

i want to loop over each email so as to perform pre-post validation.

How do i loop over email[] using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find them, and [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) to loop through them:

```
$('input[name="email[]"]').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/opIFuZA/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/opIFuZA/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

To loop over, and perform actions upon, the elements, use `each()`:

```
$('input[name="email[]"]').each(function(i,e){
    // i is the index of the current element within the collection,
    // e is the DOM node node
});
```

[Simple demonstrative example of how to use](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UDPV3/).

The `input` is an element-type selector, the `[name="email[]"]` is the element-equals selector.

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following. You need to escape '[' and ']' characters Hope it will help you.

```
$('input[name="email\\[\\]"]').each(function(){
```

})

Comment: Actually, you don't need to escape those characters (any more, but I don't believe it does any harm to do so).